# Can't initialize Spark session

Tags: rstudio

I try to initialize a session of Spark in RStudio

```
library(SparkR)

spark = sparkR.session()
```

and I get the following output:

```
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: /opt/application/Spark2/current
Launching java with spark-submit command /opt/application/Spark2/current/bin/spark-submit   sparkr-shell /tmp/RtmpHnfhH3/backend_port60069d001e5 
Error in sparkR.sparkContext(master, appName, sparkHome, sparkConfigMap,  : 
  Unexpected EOF in JVM connection data. Mismatched versions?
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an older version of SparkR e.g. 2.3.0
The old message was:

```
Version mismatch between Spark JVM and SparkR package. JVM version was 2.2.1-mapr-1803 , while R package version was 2.3.0
```

So it seems to be a SparkR bug because older versions work flawlessly. 
(I do have the same problem as you with the newest version)

You can get an old version via the R archive 
(https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SparkR/)
just run:

```
library(devtools)
install_version("SparkR", version = "2.3.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```